# Google Cloud Function : how to continues timeout function

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cron, google-cloud-functions

i have some function to get shop order data from **shopee.co.id** open api to be implemented on GF (**google function**) and trigger by cloud scheduler. the problem is.the target shop order data took me **1,5 hours** to get 10K orders data. for my understand, CF gen 2nd have max 1 hours timeout when triggered. my question is:

is it possible  to continues/retrigger the rest of code left in
function again after timeout occured either in cloud function or
cloud scheduler like snapshot?

is google function is good solution for long task like my case. if not should i use app engine? (**notes: my scripts is not web services that need flask is just one hit script to be run by cron scheduler to push data straight to bigquery after get the data from api**)

thank you

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to continues/retrigger the rest of code left in function again after timeout occured either in cloud function or cloud scheduler like snapshot?

No, it's not that simple. You will end up doing a lot of coding to correctly implement retries and snapshotting the progress of your work so you don't duplicate or miss anything.  Google Cloud won't do any of that work for you.

> is google function is good solution for long task like my case?

No, Cloud Functions is not meant for long-running batch work.

You could consider App Engine or Compute Engine instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Cloud function` V2 is not adapted for long running jobs and I think it will complicated to implement your own logic for snapshotting or retry.

You can think about other solutions :

- **Solution 1** : Apache Beam/Dataflow job

`Dataflow` is adapted for long running jobs and it's serverless, it's based on `Apache Beam` open source model.

`Beam` is proposed with `Python`, `Java` or `GO` sdk and it's easy to read an api and write the result to Bigquery via IO classes given natively by the sdk

- **Solution 2** : job on Compute Engine VM or App Engine

You can deploy your current script to Compute Engine VM or App Engine (`Google` `Python` clients), there is no limit in one hour in this case.

Comment: If i deploy my scripts either on app engine or compute engine. How can i monitoring the cron jon via cloud scheduler?

Comment: To schedule App Engine jobs : https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml

Comment: To schedule a Compute Engine instance : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/schedule-instance-start-stop

Answer (score 0):

For me, the best design here is to scale out. I mean, instead of processing 10k order on only one instance, you can do that on multiple instance. For instance, process 1k orders over 10 instances.

You can also try to leverage multi CPU processing, especially with Cloud Run.

If you can share more about the detail of the connection, and your processing flow, we can advise more clearly